# Pygame how to get previous song

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pygame, raspberry-pi3

I want to make the program to go to the previous song if the user decides to press the button (mind you I'm doing this on a raspberry pi). The problem is I cannot figure out how to make the program to get to the previous song. I got to the point where I can go to next song, I also tried 'pygame.mixer.music.rewind()' but that only goes to the beginning of the current song.

```
def prevSong():
    print("musiclist is ",musiclist)
    print('Playing previous song')
    pygame.mixer.music.rewind()

def nextSong():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    print("musiclist is ",musiclist)
    print('                      ')
    random_song = random.choice(musiclist)
    randSong = pygame.mixer.music.load(random_song)
    print('Playing next song: {}'.format(random_song))
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    musiclist.remove(random_song)
```

I want the changes to be made to prevSong(). The function nextSong() is an example to go on. Any suggestions? Thanks

Edit 1:Ok so I created a new list called 'prevSongList', but I can't get my head around as how am I supposed to get the song appended

```
def playMusic():
    pygame.mixer.init()
    print("musiclist is ",musiclist)
    print('                      ')
    random_song = random.choice(musiclist)
    randSong = pygame.mixer.music.load(random_song)
    prev = prevSongList.append(randSong)
    print('Playing song: {}'.format(random_song))
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: You should save the songs you have in an array, this way you'd just have to get the last element of the array and load it.

Comment: @LioraHaydont I made some edits to the post. I blanked as how am I supposed to get the song appended to play.

Comment: @LioraHaydontIt's also giving me an error couldn't read from RWops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed that you should save the songs in a list, you could also make a dj class so you could extend it beyond that

```
class DJSongify:

    def __init__(self):
        self.previous = location.music
        self.songlist = []   
    def songlist_continue(self,song)
        self.previous = song
        self.songlist.append(song)
```

This would let you keep track and also do other operations on your DJ class, such as doing garbage collection on the list of songs if it gets too big for the Rasberry Pi. You could even set a song list limit and handle it through the class that way.

Answer (score 1):

Like you added, you should create an array that will contain all the songs played. To be able to correctly access the previous one, you should also have a variable that tells you where you are currently in your list.

In your `prevSong` function, you could simply acces the song before you index in the list. Something like:

```
def prevSong():
    print("musiclist is ",musiclist)
    print('Playing previous song')
    #you should add a if there in case there is no previous song
    currentIndex-- #remove 1 to the current index 
    lastSong = prevSongList[currentIndex]
    #play the song
    pygame.mixer.music.load(lastSong)
```

And inside your `nextSong` function, before adding a random song, check if there isn't already a song for `currentIndex+1`.

About you error, I think it is because of the line

```
prev = prevSongList.append(randSong)
```

I'm not sure what `pygame.mixer.music.load(random_song)` returns but it might not be a string, you should use the name of the song instead:

```
prev = prevSongList.append(random_song)
```